# .NET MAUI dependency injection when to add Singleton/Transient

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, maui

I realize this question is answered on Stack Overflow, but I'm looking for an *"explain it like I'm a Golden Retriever"* explanation, as a lot of the terminology (and some of the concepts) are unfamiliar to me.

In `MauiProgram.cs`, it's necessary to put in lines of code that look like this:

```
            builder.Services.AddTransient<SecondPageViewModel>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAlertService, AlertService>();
```

I have **no idea** when to use `AddTransient` or `AddSingleton`.

I understand the Singleton design pattern and I sort of understand dependency injection, but I don't understand how these lines of code deal with dependency injection, and, frankly, I don't understand the docs.

My suspicion is that when you navigate away from a page and it's `Transient`, the state of the Page / possibly some data associated with it are deleted, so when you navigate back to it, it's like the first time it's been shown.

But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the life time definitions:

- ***Singleton*** means that an object lives as long as the application lives.
- ***Transient*** means that a new object is created every time you request a transient service.
- ***Scoped*** means a limited lifetime, how long depends on the type of application. For a web service, it's usually from receiving an HTTP request to an HTTP response being sent. In an MAUI application, I don't know. Maybe for a page like you said?

**Cleanup**

There is also something else that the IoC container takes care of. And the is freeing up resources. That's done with the `IDisposable` interface. All Singleton and Scoped services will get cleaned up.

For transients, it's harder as the IoC container just acts like a factory for them (i.e. creating a new one every time without knowing how long they will be used).

Comment: Thank you!  You've given me enough information that I know what to read up on.  My intuition sounds correct, but I'm missing a lot of basic IoC, DI principles.  But it seems straightforward.